# Allocating proper memory size

Tags: c, memory-management, sizeof, sbrk

I am having an issue with allocating the right size of memory in my program.  I do the following:

```
void * ptr = sbrk(sizeof(void *)+sizeof(unsigned int));
```

When I do this, I think it is adding too much memory to the heap because it is allocating it in units of void* instead of bytes.  How do I tell it that I want sizeof(*whatever*) to mean *whatever* bytes instead of *whatever* other units?

EDIT:

I have seen other people cast things as a char so that the compiler takes the size in bytes.  If sizeof(unsigned int) is 4 bytes, but the type that I was using is void *, will the compiler break 4 times the size of a void * instead of 4 bytes?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're adding in `sizeof(void*)` here?  What are you planning on doing with this memory?  Also, any reason that you're not using plain-ol' `malloc` here?

Comment: Short answer: Either you know what you're doing and you don't need to ask this question, or you *don't* know what you're doing and you shouldn't use `sbrk()`, but rather `malloc()`.

Comment: I am avoiding malloc because I am experimenting with some of the system calls (such as sbrk()), and I am trying to store a pointer of any type and an unsigned integer in this block of memory that I added to the heap

Comment: Just to be clear, the `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes. I don't understand what you're asking. Have you tried printing the resulting size to check if it's what you're expecting?

Comment: I trust you know what you are doing and realise that using this in place of malloc will degrade the performance of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a number of bytes as the argument of `sbrk`.

In Linux, the prototype of `sbrk` is:

```
void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);
```

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html

> sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes.

But as some people in the comments added, if you want to dynamically allocate memory you are looking for the `malloc` function and not `sbrk`. `brk` and `sbrk` are syscalls that are usually used internally for the implementation of the `malloc` user function.

Comment: so sbrk will only ever take its arguments in bytes? I seem to remember that the type of whatever memory you are allocating affects the size of either sbrk or malloc

Comment: @mrswmmr the Linux `sbrk`  function and the Standard `malloc` function take a number of bytes as their operand,

Answer (score 0):

The kernel manages process memory in a page granularity. This means the process address space must grow (or shrink) by a whole number of pages.
So even though `sbrk` gets a number of bytes, it would add at least one page to the process.